# Best Framework for Audio

Tags: iphone, core-audio, openal, audiotoolbox

In that application I am recording the voice of a human storing it in a file in NSTemporaryDirectory() and then playing it. So far I have used AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder but after some time when I record it simultaneously it plays the sound I don't know why? And more over my application crashes in iPhone 4.

Now could you please suggest me which framework to use which do recording changes pitch and can play and most importent which will work on all iPhones.
1. OpenAL
2. Core Audio 
3. AudioToobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder in one of my apps and I don't have that problem at all. 
Maybe the issue you describe is related to other problem in your app.
Are you sure you don't have another bug in your app that causes this?